# AngularJS displaying as plain text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, text

I am currently having trouble getting angular JS to display, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as it only shows up as plain text in my browser and doesn't get the info passed from the `app2.js`.
I have all dependencies properly placed in the locations listed in my code, so I'm thinking that I may have made an error in my code?
My code is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="phonecatApp" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="PhoneCat">
    <!-- AngularUI Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/ui-bootstrap-csp.css" />

</head>


<p>Total number of phones: {{phones.length}}</p>

    <body ng-controller="PhoneListController">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
                <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
                <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app2.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app2.js**

```
// Define the `phonecatApp` module
var app = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

// Define the `PhoneListController` controller on the `phonecatApp` module
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', function PhoneListController($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
      {
          name: 'Nexus S',
          snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
      }, {
          name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
          snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
      }, {
          name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
          snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
      }
    ];
});
```

Comment: your script tags does not have closing , <script src="scripts/angular.js"</script> , shouldn't it be <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>..? or is that just a typo ..?

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: app2.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: phonecatApp is not defined

Comment: angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PhoneListController' is not a function, got undefined


http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=PhoneListController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined


    at angular.js:68
    at assertArg (angular.js:1885)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1895)
    at $controller (angular.js:10210)
    at setupControllers (angular.js:9331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9116)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8510)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8390)
    at angular.js:1756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you defined your module as `app` :

```
var app = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

and are defining you controller on `phonecatApp` module. So change to:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistake in `app2.js`. You should replace `phonecatApp.controller` with `app.controller`. because you have declare `var app=...` so you should use `app.controller`. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

naming problem with module check once. replace with the phonecatApp